# Having issues starting Selenium Grid session using Chrome getting the following message Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService

Tags: c#, selenium, grid

I'm coding using C# for Selenium automation scripts, I'm using the Grid and trying to run scripts on the server. I'm getting the following error message :

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to create new service: 
 ChromeDriverService
 Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', 
 time: '2017-08-29T12:54:15.039Z'
 System info: host: 'USCDCSEL60', ip: '10.71.100.153', os.name: 'Windows 
 Server 
 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', 
 os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_144'

 Driver info: driver.version: unknown (33)
 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response 
 errorResponse)
 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String 
 driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities 
 desiredCapabilities)
 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor 
 commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, 
 ICapabilities desiredCapabilities, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, 
 ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
 at CRAFT.businesscomponents.GridTest.NetworkTest() in c:\Concept\Global 
Intranet Automation\businesscomponents\GridTest.cs:line 73}



  Here is my code :

 Public void NetworkTest()
    {
        // Create a new instance of the Chrome driver.

        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.

        // Further note that other drivers (InternetExplorerDriver,
        // ChromeDriver, etc.) will require further configuration 
        // before this example will work. See the wiki pages for the
        // individual drivers at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki
        // for further information.


        IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new 
        Uri("http://10.71.100.153:4444/wd/hub"),
        DesiredCapabilities.Chrome());


        //Notice navigation is slightly different than the Java version
        //This is because 'get' is a keyword in C#


         driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        query.SendKeys("Cheese");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the 
        // element
        query.Submit();

        // Google's search is rendered dynamically with JavaScript.
        // Wait for the page to load, timeout after 10 seconds
         WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        wait.Until((d) => { return d.Title.ToLower().StartsWith("cheese"); 
     });

        // Should see: "Cheese - Google Search"
        System.Console.WriteLine("Page title is: " + driver.Title);

        //Close the browser
        driver.Quit();

       }
    }
   }
```

The hub machine sees the script running however the Chrome driver service is not started. I assume my code needs more information such as a directory to the where the Chrome driver is located.

Comment: i'm assuming the node is running and properly connected to the hub?

Comment: connect your hub and note properly..

Comment: Yes the node and hub are connected properly

Comment: ANy coding samples for connecting the hub and node properly? Do I have to give the location of the Chrome driver on the hub when connecting the node?